# Method to get Matrix inversion of special form $(sI-A)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

I am learning Control theory , and I often encounter the following question?
$$(sI-A)^{-1}$$
for example when
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&3&1\\
1&3&1\\
1&2&2
\end{pmatrix}$$
I get $$(sI-A) = \begin{pmatrix}
s-2&-3&-1\\
-1&s-3&-1\\
-1&-2&s-2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
My idea is following
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
s-2&-3&-1&1&0&0\\
-1&s-3&-1&0&1&0\\
-1&-2&s-2&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then do a series of transformation to get the inversion of the matrix , am I right? Is there a simpler method ?

Comment: I have edited, think you

Comment: Yes, that is correct. No, there is no simpler method for computing $(sI - A)^{-1}$

Comment: If you are allowed to use e.g. wolfram alpha, do so https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Inverse+%7B%7Bs-2%2C3%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2Cs-3%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2Cs-2%7D%7D

Comment: Not simpler, but we can use the characteristic polynomial of $A$ to write $A^3$ in terms of $A^2,A,I,$   then write $(sI-A)  (bA^2 + cA + dI) = I$ and find $b,c,d$ in terms of $s$

Comment: What is the principle of this method? Is Hamiton-Cayley Theoreom?@Will Jagy

Comment: @Hugo right. If you have a nice function $h(x)$ with a power series  with a large enough radius of convergence, we can expect to find $h(A)$ by the same power series, with the change that the entire infinite series can be expressed as a finite expression such as my $dI + cA + b A^2$  For your example, changing to letter $x$ for familiarity, name constant $a$  and $h(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
    p(\lambda)= \lambda^3-7\lambda^2+10\lambda+4.
$$
Therefore $p(A)=0$. From this,
\begin{align}
     -p(\lambda)I & =p(A)-p(\lambda)I \\
                  &=(A^3-\lambda^3I)-7(A^2-\lambda^2I)+10(A-\lambda I) \\
         &= (A-\lambda I)(A^2+\lambda A+\lambda^2I)-7(A-\lambda I)(A+\lambda I)+10(A-\lambda I) \\
         &= (A-\lambda I)(A^2+\lambda A+\lambda^2 I-7A-7\lambda I+10I) \\
         &= (A-\lambda I)(\lambda^2 I+\lambda (A-7I)+A^2-7A+10I)
\end{align}
Hence, if $p(\lambda)\ne 0$, then $A-\lambda I$ is invertible, with inverse given by
$$
          (A-\lambda I)^{-1}=-\frac{1}{p(\lambda)}(\lambda ^2I+\lambda (A-7I)+A^2-7A+10I)
$$